# Driver's mate or assistant in American English

Tags: word-choice, american-english

What is the most used term in American English from the items below:

- > Driver’s mate
- > Driver’s assistant

I.e., someone who travels with the driver of a large goods vehicle and helps with the loading/unloading and other aspects of making deliveries.

Comment: I guess you mean American English? What is a driver's mate/assistant?

Comment: A driver's mate is someone who travels with the driver of a large goods vehicle and helps with the loading/unloading and other aspects of making deliveries.  I have no idea what Americans call them.

Comment: I think "driver's assistant", "driver assistant", or maybe "truck driver assistant" sounds much more American; we don't use "mate" as a title much other than for [ship's mates](https://www.sokanu.com/careers/shipmate/).  [Here's a US job listing for a "Heavy Truck Driver Assistant" showing the use of the term.](http://www.lausd.k12.ca.us/lausd/offices/personnel/class/class_comp/cds/CODE5858.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, I have never been to Britain, but I get the feeling that what you're talking about must be much more common there than it is here. As far as I know, most American drivers have to do the lifting themselves. Sometimes for large jobs they have additional people with them, who I might just call "helpers," but most delivery drivers I can think of are pretty much on their own.